# Issues with User Input and Win Condition

Tags: c

I've been working on a simple Hangman game in C and I've encountered a couple of issues that i'm struggling to resolve. The game seems to have problems with user input and the win condition , i am facing problem when the userInput is not in the word and deduction of chances and i want to restrict the user input to one character at a time
here is what i have written

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "./random.h"
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <windows.h>
#define ARRAY_SIZE sizeof(words) / sizeof(words[0])
//------------------------------------------------------------
int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    char *words[] = {
        "hello",
        "superman"};
    char *random_word = random(ARRAY_SIZE, words);
    char userinput;
    bool gameover = false;
    int length = 0;
    int index;
    int chances = 5;
    char *empty_list = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 100);
    char letter;
    //-----------------------------------------------------------
    while (random_word[length] != '\0')
    {
        length++;
    }
    for (index = 0; index < length; index++)
    {
        empty_list[index] = '_';
    }
    empty_list[length] = '\0';

    printf("\n%s\n", empty_list);

    while (!gameover)
    {
        printf("Guess the word: ");
        scanf("%c*c", &userinput);
        for (index = 0; index < length; index++)
        {
            letter = random_word[index];
            if (letter == userinput)
            {
                empty_list[index] = letter;
                printf("\n%s\n", empty_list);
                Beep(720, 300);
            }
            if (userinput != random_word[index])
            {
                chances = chances - 1;
                printf("\nYou have %d chances left", chances);
            }
            if (empty_list[index] == '_' || chances == 0)
            {
                gameover = false;
            }
            else
            {
                gameover = true;
            }
        }
    }
    if (gameover)
        printf("YOU WON ");
}
```

Comment: You should get used to always check the return value of `scanf` function. What is this format string `"%c*c"` supposed to match?

Comment: Your logic is flawed. You reduce `chances` for each letter of your word that does not match the input. You should only decrement once after the whole word was checked. Also, in case you have the same letter twice, you should only print `empty_list` after the whole word was handled. You need to reduce your `for` loop. Check and replace everything and remember if you found something. Then only after the loop do the further handling

Comment: sir,i want user to input the character one at a time 
----
a
a------

but i my code i am able to write apple as a whole and i directly win , i want to restrict that 
------
apple

Answer (score 0):

Trying out your code, basically there are issues in the "for" loop testing when to decrement the chance counter and determine if the game is over.  Testing it out in the terminal provided the following results.

```
craig@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/Hangman/bin/Release$ ./Hangman 

_____
Guess the word: d

You have 4 chances left
You have 3 chances left
You have 2 chances left
You have 1 chances left
You have 0 chances leftGuess the word: d

You have -1 chances left
You have -2 chances left
You have -3 chances left
You have -4 chances left
You have -5 chances leftGuess the word: 
You have -6 chances left
You have -7 chances left
You have -8 chances left
You have -9 chances left
You have -10 chances leftGuess the word: d

- - -

You have -57 chances left
You have -58 chances left
You have -59 chances left
You have -60 chances left
You have -61 chances leftGuess the word: 
You have -62 chances left
You have -63 chances left
You have -64 chances left
You have -65 chances left
hello
YOU WON craig@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/Hangman/bin/Release$
```

As can be seen, the counter is allowed to go negative, and the program will allow letters to be entered until the word is found.  And then, the person is determined to have won.

The two main issues are that the counter can be decremented every time the character guess is wrong and the "gameover" flag is set to "false" until all correct letters are guessed.

```
if (empty_list[index] == '_' || chances == 0)
```

With that following is a refactored version of your code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define ARRAY_SIZE sizeof(words) / sizeof(words[0])

//------------------------------------------------------------
int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    char *words[] = {"hello", "superman", "dart", "flask"};
    int x = rand() % ARRAY_SIZE;                /* Using standard rand() function       */
    char random_word[20];
    strcpy(random_word, words[x]);              /* Use standard string copy function    */
    char userinput;
    bool gameover = false, found, underscore;
    int length = 0;
    int index;
    int chances = 5;
    char empty_list[100];
    char letter;

    //-----------------------------------------------------------

    length = strlen(random_word);               /* Use standard string length function  */

    for (index = 0; index < length; index++)
    {
        empty_list[index] = '_';
    }

    empty_list[length] = '\0';

    printf("%s\n", empty_list);

    while (!gameover)
    {
        printf("Guess the word: ");
        scanf(" %c", &userinput);
        found = false;
        underscore = false;
        for (index = 0; index < length; index++)
        {
            letter = random_word[index];
            if (letter == userinput)
            {
                empty_list[index] = letter;
                printf("Beep..:\n");            /* Test run in a console    */
                found = true;
                //Beep(720, 300);               /* Test run in a console    */
            }

        }

        printf("Current: %s\n", empty_list);    /* Test run in a console    */

        if (found == false)
        {
            chances--;                                      /* Decrement the chance counter */
            printf("You have %d chances left\n", chances);
        }

        for (index = 0; index < length; index++)
        {
            if ((empty_list[index] == '_' && chances == 0)) /* Game is over if there are still underscores and the chance count is zero */
            {
                gameover = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        for (index = 0; index < length; index++)            /* Check if any underscores remain in the empty list    */
            if (empty_list[index] == '_')
            {
                underscore = true;
                break;
            }

        if (!underscore)                                    /* If no more underscore characters are in the empty list - the game is won */
        {
            gameover = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (gameover && (chances > 0))
        printf("YOU WON\n");
    else
        printf("Sorry, you lost.  The word was %s\n", random_word);
}
```

My apologies for including the full code, as the refactored bits were dispersed throughout the program.  Following are some key points.

- First off, since I was testing out this code on my Linux virtual machine, any windows related references were removed.
- Also, including the "stdlib.h" file allowed for the use of the standard random number function (rand()).
- To utilize customary string functionality, the "string.h" reference was included.
- As noted in the added comments in the refactored code, standard string functions were used to copy the random word, and determine the length of the string for the various "for" loop processing.
- Additional Boolean variables were added to determine if and when all of the underscores had been replaced with properly guessed characters and if a guessed character was found in the random word.
- The "if" testing blocks were relocated outside of the initial "for" loop for determination of found characters and/or the decrementing of the chance count.
- If a guessed character was not found, and the chance count had been decremented to zero, the "gameover" flag was set to true, and the "while" loop was exited - the player had lost.
- Also, if a check of the "empty_list" array no longer contained any underscore characters, the "gameover" flag was set to true, and the "while" loop was exited - the player had won.

With these bits of refactoring following were a couple of test runs of the program.

```
craig@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/Hangman/bin/Release$ ./Hangman 
_____
Guess the word: d
Current: _____
You have 4 chances left
Guess the word: d
Current: _____
You have 3 chances left
Guess the word: d
Current: _____
You have 2 chances left
Guess the word: d
Current: _____
You have 1 chances left
Guess the word: d
Current: _____
You have 0 chances left
Sorry, you lost.  The word was hello
craig@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/Hangman/bin/Release$ ./Hangman 
____
Guess the word: d
Beep..:
Current: d___
Guess the word: a
Beep..:
Current: da__
Guess the word: r
Beep..:
Current: dar_
Guess the word: t
Beep..:
Current: dart
YOU WON
```

FYI, for the test, the program just prints the word "Beep" as I did not have access to that library and function.

The take-away from this is be cognizant of functionality available for handling of character arrays with "string.h" and be careful of testing logic, especially "and" or "or" logic ("&&" "||").  You may want to delve into some additional "C" literature as it pertains to character arrays and Boolean functions.

Comment: `putchar( '\a' );` == a short "beep"... An often overlooked standard escape code....